# Crear una calculadora de niveles en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy tratando de hacer dentro de esta función un calculadora de niveles que me gustaría implementar en un programa.
***quiero hacer algo como esto:***

```
#puntos | nivel | función matemática | resultado 
#25      nivel 1 =                     =  25
#55      nivel 2 = 25 + 25 + 5         =  55
#90      nivel 3 = 55 + 25 + 5 + 5     =  90
#130     nivel 4 = 90 + 25 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 130
#Etc...
```

**aquí** *dejo mi código para que lo revisen, tambien quisiera saber que anda mal con este.*

```
def level_returner(power):
    require_power = 25
    level_up = 0
    while not require_power > power:
        level_up += 1
        require_power += level_up *+ 5
    return "punto escrito:%d nivel actual:%d punto necesarios:%d" % (power,level_up,require_power)
print(level_returner(55))
```

Comment: Que significa la variable `power`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que hay varias cosas mal en tu código:

- Olvidaste sumar 25 cada vez que sube el nivel
- La condición del bucle está mal, pues cuando se alcanza el nivel (55) no se saldría sino que aún se ejecutaría una vez mas, pues usaste `>` cuando debe ser `>=`. De hecho, es más legible si quitas el `not` y lo cambias por `<`
- Por otro lado tu contador de niveles comienza en 0 en vez de 1 por lo que dará 1 menos de lo que buscas. Se arregla inicializándolo con 1 e incrementándolo después de calcular la puntuación en vez de antes.

Arreglando estos tres problemas:

```
def level_returner(power):
    require_power = 25
    level_up = 1
    while require_power < power:
        require_power += 25 + level_up * 5
        level_up += 1
    return "punto escrito:%d nivel actual:%d punto necesarios:%d" % (power,level_up,require_power)
print(level_returner(55))
```

Salida:

```
punto escrito:55 nivel actual:2 punto necesarios:55
```

Ya parece funcionar correctamente, al menos para el caso 55. La verdad es que no tengo del todo claro si funciona en el resto de casos porque tampoco me quedó del todo claro lo que se supone que hace esa función.